# signed Desktop bridge app receives "untrusted" elevate prompt

Tags: uwp, elevated-privileges

I have an Desktop bridge app signed with visual studio 2019 created certificate.
But when I lauch an elevated execute file in my app, then I received an yellow elevate prompt UAC dialog.
As bellow:
[image]

Any one know why it is happened?

The sample code is below:
https://github.com/tomxue/testApp

Thanks!

Comment: The dialog displayed when click exe file, right?  have you tried package the desktop bridge app to  installation appx file?

Comment: Hi Nico.
I have packaged the desktop briage app to appx file. and install it completely.
And this dialog is my client.exe launch itself as administrator, then it need to elevate.

Comment: So, you launch the app with app's shortcut(administrator),right?

Comment: yes, launch the app with the app's shortcut, then launch itself as administrator in code.

Comment: *launch itself as administrator in code*, We can't reproduce, could you mind share us with [mcve] and the detail steps?

Comment: our launch code is :
 System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 p.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = Names.CommandLineArgs.ServiceStart_By_Client;
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
 p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
 p.Start();

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I forget to say that this is reproduced only on windows version 1909 (10.0.18363)

Comment: Have you tested with latest version 19041?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't reproduce on version 19041, but we don't know whether it is the root cause.

Comment: It's hard to determine the issue, if it could not reproduce in latest version, we suggest to edit the app's target version to 1904.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFTour app need to run on all version above 18362. 
And I upload my sample code to : https://github.com/tomxue/testApp.

Comment: I have tested in 1904, and it also show the uac dialog. I think it is by-design, and  you could set uac never notify in the control panel for disable the dialog.

Comment: The UAC dialog in 19041 is different with 18363. 19041 is because the exe is not signed with CA certificate. But 18363 is don't recognize the certificate that VS created.